# Managing offsets in apache nifi custom processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am looking into creating a custom processor for ingesting data from a custom source where there is no existing nifi processor.

I have been trying to understand the mechanics of how the Nifi Components work and have seen some good documentation on how to create a custom processor, however, I cannot see anything about managing offsets.  Lets say I have a Processor that runs 1 second, but needs to continue processing from some arbitrary offset, which may or may not yield results every second.

My current understanding is that the "onTrigger" method is the place to implement such logic, however, Im uncertain if there are any mechanics in Nifi I can leverage to mark the offset of previous executions so I know where to continue from.

Does Nifi have some capability to record some "state" of the offset between executions for custom components?

Comment: in general nifi is not a storage. how long you want to store the "state"? should it be shared between nodes of cluster or it should be managed by each node? should it be permanent and keep the value after restart?

Answer (score 1):

NiFi has the capability for components to store state related to their processing, many built-in components enable this feature in order to keep track of offsets (see [GenerateTableFetch](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.11.3/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/GenerateTableFetch.java) for a processor example, or [SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.11.3/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-bundle/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-task/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/reporting/SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask.java) for a reporting task example)